# Kotlin Coroutines - Suspend function returning a Flow runs forever

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am making a network repository that supports multiple data retrieval configs, therefore I want to separate those configs' logic into functions.

However, I have a config that fetches the data continuously at specified intervals. Everything is fine when I emit those values to the original Flow. But when I take the logic into another function and return another Flow through it, it stops caring about its coroutine scope. Even after the scope's cancelation, it keeps on fetching the data.

**TLDR:** Suspend function returning a flow runs forever when currentCoroutineContext is used to control its loop's termination.

What am I doing wrong here?
Here's the simplified version of my code:

***Fragment calling the viewmodels function that basically calls the getData()***

```
 lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getLatestDataList()
        }
```

***Repository***

```
suspend fun getData(config: MyConfig): Flow<List<Data>>
{
    return flow {

        when (config)
        {
            CONTINUOUS ->
            {
                //It worked fine when fetchContinuously was ingrained to here and emitted directly to the current flow
                //And now it keeps on running eternally
                fetchContinuously().collect { updatedList ->
                    emit(updatedList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//Note logic of this function is greatly reduced to keep the focus on the problem
private suspend fun fetchContinuously(): Flow<List<Data>>
{
    return flow {
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive)
        {

            val updatedList = fetchDataListOverNetwork().await()

            if (updatedList != null)
            {
                emit(updatedList)
            }

            delay(refreshIntervalInMs)
        }

        Timber.i("Context is no longer active - terminating the continuous-fetch coroutine")
    }
}


private suspend fun fetchDataListOverNetwork(): Deferred<List<Data>?> =

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        return@withContext async {

            var list: List<Data>? = null

            try
            {
                val response = apiService.getDataList().execute()

                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null)
                {
                    list = response.body()!!.list
                }
                else
                {
                    Timber.w("Failed to fetch data from the network database. Error body: ${response.errorBody()}, Response body: ${response.body()}")
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception)
            {
                Timber.w("Exception while trying to fetch data from the network database. Stacktrace: ${e.printStackTrace()}")
            }
            finally
            {
                return@async list
            }
            list //IDE is not smart enough to realize we are already returning no matter what inside of the finally block; therefore, this needs to stay here
        }

    }
```

Comment: Using suspend keyword is not recommended to use in a function that returns Flow
https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/type/Code%20Smell/RSPEC-6309

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is a solution to your problem, but you do not need to have a suspending function that returns a Flow. The lambda you are passing is a suspending function itself:

```
fun <T> flow(block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit): Flow<T> (source)
```

Here is an example of a flow that repeats a (GraphQl) query (simplified - without type parameters) I am using:

```
    override fun query(query: Query,
                       updateIntervalMillis: Long): Flow<Result<T>> {
    return flow {
        // this ensures at least one query
        val result: Result<T> = execute(query)
        emit(result)

        while (coroutineContext[Job]?.isActive == true && updateIntervalMillis > 0) {
            delay(updateIntervalMillis)

            val otherResult: Result<T> = execute(query)
            emit(otherResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just backing up this answer with a good reference https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-6309

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good at Flow but I think the problem is that you are delaying only the getData() flow instead of delaying both of them.
Try adding this:

```
suspend fun getData(config: MyConfig): Flow<List<Data>>
{
    return flow {

        when (config)
        {
            CONTINUOUS ->
            {
                fetchContinuously().collect { updatedList ->
                    emit(updatedList)
                    delay(refreshIntervalInMs)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take note of the `delay(refreshIntervalInMs)`.