# Build Flow result based on call to a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning coroutines and need some help to understand a basic use case.

Implement a non-blocking method that:

- Fetches a single item from a (reactive) DB
- Determines a range (i.e. the month that the item lives in) based on that item's timestamp
- Fetches all items in that month
- Returns the items as `Flow`

### Approach

Because it must return a `Flow` I will not use `suspend` (like I would when returning a single item). Returning `Flow` and `suspend` (which kind of returns a `Mono`) are most commonly mutually exclusive, right?

So I came up with this signature:

```
override fun getHistory(beforeUtcMillisExclusive: Long): Flow<Item>
```

Trying an implementation:

```
val itemInNextPeriod = itemRepository.findOneByTimestampLessThan(beforeUtcMillisExclusive)
if (itemInNextPeriod == null) {
  return emptyFlow()
} else {
  val range = calcRange(itemInNextPeriod.timestamp)
  return itemRepository.findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThan(range.start, range.end)
}
```

This gives me on the very first line:

> Suspend function 'findOneByTimestampLessThan' should be called only
> from a coroutine or another suspend function

I understand the problem that we are not allowed to call a suspend function here and the proposed solution by IntelliJ "adding suspend" does not make sense, when already returning a flow.

So, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211064/kotlin-coroutines-suspend-function-returning-a-flow-runs-forever) I got the idea of using a `return flow {...}`:

```
return flow {
  val itemInNextPeriod = itemRepository.findOneByTimestampLessThan(beforeUtcMillisExclusive)
  if (itemInNextPeriod == null) {
    return@flow
  } else {
    val range = calcRange(itemInNextPeriod.timestamp)
    return@flow itemRepository.findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThan(range.start, 
  range.end)
  }
}
```

The second repository call `findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThan` returns `Flow<Item>` and I do not understand why I cannot return it.

> This function must return a value of type Unit
> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Unit
> Found:
> Flow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return@flow` returns from the lambda, not from enclosing function.
You need to reemit items from `Flow` returned by `findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThan` call into `Flow` you're building with `flow` function:

```
return flow {
    val itemInNextPeriod = itemRepository.findOneByTimestampLessThan(beforeUtcMillisExclusive)
    if (itemInNextPeriod != null) {
        val range = calcRange(itemInNextPeriod.timestamp)
        emitAll(itemRepository.findByTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndTimestampLessThan(range.start, range.end))
    }
}
```